# Wordpress Deleting downloaded images on metabox with file

Tags: wordpress, file

```
require_once(ABSPATH . '/wp-load.php');
                            require_once(ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/file.php');
                            require_once(ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/image.php');

                            $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => FALSE );
                            $count_files = count( $_FILES['my_files'] );
                            $uploads = wp_upload_dir();
                            foreach ( range( 0, $count_files ) as $i ) {

                                 // create an array of the $_FILES for each file
                                 $file_array = array(
                                    'name'     => $_FILES['files']['name'][$i],
                                    'type'     => $_FILES['files']['type'][$i],
                                    'tmp_name' => $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i],
                                    'error'    => $_FILES['files']['error'][$i],
                                    'size'     => $_FILES['files']['size'][$i],
                                );

                                // check to see if the file name is not empty
                                if ( !empty( $file_array['name'] ) ) {

                                    // upload the file to the server
                                    $uploaded_file = wp_handle_upload( $file_array, $upload_overrides );

                                    // checks the file type and stores in in a variable
                                    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $uploaded_file['file'] ), null );   
                                    if ( $uploaded_file && !isset( $uploaded_file['error'] ) ) {
                                                $ufiles = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_files', true );
                                                if( empty( $ufiles ) ) $ufiles = array();
                                                $ufiles[] = $uploaded_file;
                                                update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_files', $ufiles );

                                    }
                                 }
                             }
```

I am able to download files to metabox thanks to this code.

Output of the database is looks like what i show in the below

```
a:2:{i:0;a:3:{s:4:"file";s:48:"D:xampphtdocswp/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/2.jpg";s:3:"url";s:52:"http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/2.jpg";s:4:"type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}i:1;a:3:{s:4:"file";s:59:"D:xampphtdocswp/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/2da83a4s-960.jpg";s:3:"url";s:63:"http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/2da83a4s-960.jpg";s:4:"type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}}
```

I want to delete the images that i dont want with delete_post_meta method while i am selecting checkboxes on my update page.

```
                            $galleri = get_post_meta($id,'my_files',true);



<div class="galeri">

     <?php
     foreach($galleri as  $galeri){

echo "<div style='margin:10px;display:inline-block;'><input type='checkbox' name='car_image_delete[]' value='".$galeri['url']."' /><img src='".$galeri['url']."' width='150' height='150'/></div>";
                                        }


                                   ?>
                               </div>
```

I appreciate if you help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Use `update_post_meta()` function instead of `delete_post_meta()`.

While using `delete_post_meta()`, it will delete custom fields.

So if you want to delete particular one file. You need to use `update_post_meta()`.

```
$string = 'a:2:{i:0;a:3:{s:4:"file";s:48:"D:xampphtdocswp/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/2.jpg";s:3:"url";s:52:"http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/2.jpg";s:4:"type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}i:1;a:3:{s:4:"file";s:59:"D:xampphtdocswp/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/2da83a4s-960.jpg";s:3:"url";s:63:"http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/2da83a4s-960.jpg";s:4:"type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}}';
$arr = unserialize($string);  //USE get_post_meta() function instead of
$index = array_search('http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/2da83a4s-960.jpg',array_column( $arr, 'url')); //search index
echo $index;
if (array_key_exists($index,$arr))
{
    unset($arr[$index]); //remove array index 
}
print_r($arr);  //array with only value. 
//use array_values() to reindex
update_post_meta($post_id, 'my_files', $arr); //update post meta
```

Comment: Warning: unserialize() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in D:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-content\themes\snarent\page_edit.php on line 147

Warning: array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in D:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-content\themes\snarent\page_edit.php on line 148

Warning: array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in D:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-content\themes\snarent\page_edit.php on line 148

Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in D:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-content\themes\snarent\page_edit.php on line 150

Comment: Have you added $string value or another value? @M.UNLU

Comment: $metatable = $wpdb->prefix."postmeta";
         $string = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_value FROM $metatable where post_id=%d AND meta_key='my_files'",$id));

         $arr = unserialize($string);  //USE get_post_meta() function instead of
         $index = array_search($car_image_delete[0],array_column( $arr, 'url')); //search index
         echo $index;
         if (array_key_exists($index,$arr))
         {
          unset($arr[$index]); //remove array index 
         }

Comment: it might problem in $string variable. print_r or echo that variable. @M.UNLU

Comment: print_r($arr); -> http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/referans10-1.png1Array ( [0] => Array ( [file] => D:xampphtdocswp/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/2.jpg [url] => http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/2.jpg [type] => image/jpeg ) )

Comment: Okay so before execution, array has two value and after process it has only one value :). @M.UNLU

Comment: i want to turn this into dynamic state and i want to delete images that i post as registered advert @vrajesh

Comment: @M.UNLU you have already set "url" to checkbox value so just retrieve checkbox checked value and pass to array search.it might generate error if array is empty after get_post_meta function. thx